# Python - how to open a file that is not yet written to disk?

Tags: python, file-io, flask

I am using a [script](https://dpk.net/2013/02/21/simple-python-script-to-strip-exif-data-from-a-jpeg/)  to strip exif data from uploaded JPGs in Python, before writing them to disk. I'm using Flask, and the file is brought in through requests

```
file = request.files['file']
```

strip the exif data, and then save it

```
f = open(file) 
image = f.read()
f.close()
outputimage = stripExif(image)
f = ('output.jpg', 'w')
f.write(outputimage)
f.close()
f.save(os.path.join(app.config['IMAGE_FOLDER'], filename))
```

Open isn't working because it only takes a string as an argument, and if I try to just set `f=file`, it throws an error about tuple objects not having a write attribute. How can I pass the current file into this function before it is read?

Comment: `open()` takes the path of the target file as argument (not the contents). `f = open(PATH,'w')` then `f.write(data)` then `f.close()` creates the file, writes data to it and closes it. What's f.save() ?

Comment: It was formerly file.save, I'm just tring to save the file to disk after stripping the metadata

Comment: `file.save` does not exist. I think you are mixing up / confusing GUI concepts with Python File Object concepts... I advise you to read about File Objects in the Python manual.

Comment: My question: What is the value of `request.files['file']`? Also: instead of open-write-close it is much nicer to write: `with open('output.jpg', 'wb') as f: f.write(outputimage)` Note that you should open the file in binary mode ('wb') if you don't want trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` is a `FileStorage`, described in http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage

As the doc says, `stream` represents the stream of data for this file, usually under the form of a pointer to a temporary file, and most function are proxied.

You probably can do something like:

```
file = request.files['file']
image = file.read()
outputimage = stripExif(image)
f = open(os.path.join(app.config['IMAGE_FOLDER'], 'output.jpg'), 'w')
f.write(outputimage)
f.close()
```

Comment: Works, thank you. One question: from a speed/connectivity standpoint, is it better to do operations on a file (like stripping metadata) before it is saved, or save it to disk and then strip it?

Comment: that really depends on the implementation of the server. the files in `request.files` may be already saved to disk, or may be simply buffered in memory, that is not specified. I would say that it is not necessary to save the file first before striping it, but i don't have much arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try the io package, which has a BufferedReader(), ala:

```
import io

f = io.BufferedReader(request.files['file'])
...
```

Comment: Not working for me, I get an error with werkzeug: 
'AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'readable'

Comment: Can you figure out the type? ie: print type(request.files['file'])

Answer (score 0):

```
file = request.files['file']
image = stripExif(file.read())
file.close()
filename = 'whatever' # maybe you want to use request.files['file'].filename
dest_path = os.path.join(app.config['IMAGE_FOLDER'], filename)
with open(dest_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(image)
```